# Java script works only first time on JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am using following code in my JSP page to disable parent window when popup open

```
window.opener.document.body.disabled=true;
    document.onmousedown = focusPopup; 
    document.onkeyup = focusPopup; 
    document.onmousemove = focusPopup; 
function focusPopup() {
    window.focus(); 
  }
```

but it work only for first time,

When page gets refreshed or request resubmit, all controls, links tabs of parent window are enabled and can be used/clicked,

though it makes parent window appear as disabled, it actually dont make it disabled.

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "page gets refreshed or request resubmit"? Do you mean the parent page is refreshed?

Comment: Well, if the page is refreshed, it is a whole new page. The old state (disabled) doesnt count anymore.

Comment: Yes, when first time I click this search button on my JSP page a popup appears and above code is executed and everything works fine but when I close the pop up and refresh the parent page and then click search button, popup window appears and parent window appear as disabled but all the links and control are working this time on parent page.

Answer (score 0):

When the page is refreshed, the whole HTML is fetched again. Any changes done through javascript are lost. You will have to add additional logic to handle such cases. There are a couple of approaches involving "hidden form parameter" and "Cookie" described [here](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php) which can be used in this situation.

The changes needed in the javacript will be:

1. Set a hidden form field or cookie value when the popup is opened.
2. Add additional logic upon "onload" of parent page to check if the value is set, if yes disable the controls.

Personally I would prefer the Form based approach as the cookie based approach may be tricker (You will need to clear cookie value when the popup is closed otherwise the form may appear disabled when it is opened the next time!).